# Wait until HTML5 video has finished playing

Tags: javascript, html

```html
<style>
video
{
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
</style><script type="text/javascript">
var myVideo = document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0];

myVideo.addEventListener("ended", function() {
 window.location = "http://mariopaintforums.ddns.net/secret/contin_midi/";
}, true);
</script><body><center><video src="vid.mp4" autoplay>ur brosr is no html5 coocpopabl</video></center></body>
```

I want to redirect to a different page when a  is done playing. Is this possible?

I don't want to try to "wait" for the amount of time that the video itself occupies, because it may take a while to load and it won't finish playing correctly.

The current code with the non-working answer is above.

Comment: Event driven code. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Media_events

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the video an `id` and create the event handler outside the event listener. Go to: [<kbd>**PLUNKER**</kbd>](http://embed.plnkr.co/dY7AXNPS45I3LFaFIIJi/) and/or review Snippet below:

BTW, I noticed the code given has `<style>` and `<script>` tags before the starting tag of `<body>`. The only thing that should ever be before the `<body>` tag is it's only sibling that being the end tag of `</head>`. Copy the way the layout is in my demos and you should be OK. Place `<style>` in `<head>` and `<script>` before the closing tag of `</body>`.

**SNIPPET**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>
  <h1>index.html</h1>
  <video id="vid1" class="vid" src="http://html5demos.com/assets/dizzy.mp4" controls autoplay></video>

  <script>
    var vid = document.getElementById('vid1');
    var loc = 'http://example.com';
    vid.addEventListener('ended', function(e) {
      jumpTo(loc);
    }, false);

    function jumpTo(url) {
      window.location = url;
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I 'fixed' the layout and stuff, but still no dice? Here, look at this. See a problem? `<head><style>
video
{
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
</style></head><body><script type="text/javascript">
var myVideo = document.getElementById('dead');

myVideo.addEventListener('ended', function(e) {
 window.location = 'contin_midi';
}, true);
</script><center><video id="dead" src="vid.mp4" autoplay>ur brosr is no html5 coocpopabl</video></center></body>`

Comment: Place `<video>` before `<script>` and remove `<center>`. Where is this `contin_midi` ? `window.location` value should be a string having at least a `/` or `#` like that of an url AFAIK. Did the Snippet work as you wanted?

Comment: >> nvm. I fixed it. answering it correct. [here's the result](http://mariopaintforums.ddns.net/secret)

Comment: Ha! Indeed Fred is dead.

Answer (score 3):

You can listen to the [`ended` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Media_events) of the player, and perform your redirect in the callback function.

```
// Alternatively, use a jQuery selector to get your video element.
var myVideo = document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0];

myVideo.addEventListener("ended", function() {
    console.log("The video has just ended!");
    // Let's redirect now
    window.location = "your_new_url";
}, true);
```

Comment: That isn't redirecting me, and it's not logging to the console either.

Comment: I think that solution is the same as the one you accepted, you probably just didn't select the video element.